# What's the different of "classify" between softmax, logistic and svm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, svm, caffe, logistic-regression, softmax

I'm using caffe to do the object detection with SSD model, and recently work I adjust the loss type of "MultiBoxLoss".
In the multibox_loss_layer.cpp file, its loss has SOFTMAX as default and LOGISTIC option, I add the hingeloss(SVM) option into caffe code, and do the training but the result is bad.

Now the boss want me to use SVM to classify the feature map by python sklearn.

And a question come across to me, in the multibox_loss_layer.cpp file, there can use the softmax, logistic and hingeloss to calculate the loss. On this step, its data is just "one-dimension", but the feature map is high-dimension, and I internet the article, it seem softmax can't classify high-dimension data.

Ex: if there have three class: cat, dog and rabbit, then it's one-dimension data just have three value to represent cat, dog and rabbit(one value for each class), but the high-dimension data, it have many value(like feature map) for each class, and on the high-dimension case, softmax seems have no work for this.

so I wonder what's the different between softmax, logistic and SVM. Can anybody help? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Never seen applying SVM loss function into NN. However softmax is a loss function which should be used in order to optimize solution multiclass classifiaction problem. Softmax "transform" NN outputs into probability of each class occurance. Logistic function usually optimize each neuron output as a logistic problem, so it's not force output to be only one class. You should use this function if you want to solve multi labeling problem.

SVM is not a function, is a different classifier. There is no sense in comparing softmax with SVM, because first one is a loss function second one is a classifier.